# BICEP module deploy virtual network, but not NSG based upon if statement

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, infrastructure-as-code, azure-bicep

I have a basic BICEP module that deploys a virtual network with subnets and NSGs. 1 of the subnets is for an azure firewall. The azure firewall subnet cannot be attached to an NSG so I have put a condition to not deploy an nsg to the azure firewall subnet, but I cannot get this to work. When it runs its returns an error:

```
      {
    "code": "MissingJsonReferenceId",
    "message": "Value for reference id is missing. Path properties.subnets[6].properties.networkSecurityGroup."
  },
```

The condition is

```
id: VNetSettings.subnets[j].unique == false  ?  json('{"id": "[resourceId(\'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups\', concat(\'nsg-snet-${vNetName}-${VNetSettings.subnets[j].name}\'))]"') : json('null')
```

The condition evaluates the `VnetSettings.subnets.unique == false` and if `false` then the nsg will be deployed, but if the `VNetSettings.subnets.unique` == `true` then it should be `json('null')` and not deploy the NSG.

the `false` subnets deploy and attach the NSG, but the `true` throw this the error:

```
    "code": "MissingJsonReferenceId",
    "message": "Value for reference id is missing. Path properties.subnets[6].properties.networkSecurityGroup."
  },
```

Please someone help :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working now. The trick is to put the condition on the `properties` rather than within the `networkSecurityGroup` property